# Getting resource ID from bitmap/drawable in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap drawable image to be displayed in ImageView, below is my code:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapGrass = (BitmapDrawable)
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.grass);
bitmapGrass.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
```

I want to set that bitmap as background for ImageView, like this:

```
ImageView bgGrass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_grass);
bgGrass.setBackground(bitmapGrass);
```

Now the problem is, the method `setBackground()` is added in API level 16, but I want my app to support API level 4. I know I can use this code:

```
bgGrass.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapGrass);
```

But the method `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated. The other way to set the background is using the method `setBackgroundResource(int)`, but the required parameter is integer (not drawable).
Is there any way to implement that bitmap without using deprecated method, perhaps converting the bitmap drawable into resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's fine to call `setBackgroundDrawable` though it's deprecated in newer platforms. you can check the sdk level at runtime and call the specific method:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            //call setBackground()
} else {
            //call settBackgroundDrawable()
}
```